# Book about a woman who’s sent to a planet and meets a man with piercing blue eyes

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m trying to find the name of a book I read in high school. It was a sci fi book about a woman who’s sent to a planet and meets a man with super piercing blue eyes. They’re both from Earth but are on some sort of journey?? And on the planet there’s a road to follow and I remember at some point there’s a town or settlement that’s right before the big “gate” to finish the journey.

The ending is both of them going back to Earth I think and they don’t remember each other even though they fell in love during the book. The only other detail I really remember is that when the main character meets the man with blue eyes he’s peeking out from behind a rock. Also there’s creatures on this planet that are dangerous.

I read it some time in 2016-2018, and the cover was very colorful with like a big starry sky and moon and then the road - I don’t completely remember it. The book’s plot/storyline overall was very conceptual and almost “spiritual” - as far as the journey they were on and why and what it took to finish it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When were you in high school?  The year will help.  Also, can you describe the cover?

Comment: @DavidW - it was sometime in 2016-2018, and the cover was very colorful with like a big starry sky and moon and then the road. i don’t completely remember it. the book’s plot/storyline overall was very conceptual and almost “spiritual” - as far as the journey they were on and why and what it took to finish it